# Is there a way to write async await code that responds to onkeypress events?

Tags: javascript, async-await, onkeypress

I'd like to write a `readKey` function that's `async`, and then `await` each key being pressed in the browser.

I'd like to build this up into synchronous, normal-looking code that's all based on `async`-`await`.

So then I could write a `readLine` function that does `await readKey()` until the user hits [enter], and delete the last key if the user hits [back], etc.

And then I could write functions that `await readLine()`, and write functions that call them, etc.

I just don't know how to bridge the gap between writing a `document.onkeypress` handler...  and putting the keys in that event into some `async readKey` function that I'd write.  In other languages, I could use other multi-threading primitives to get there, but I can't figure out how to in js.  I was trying to figure out if there was some way to `yield` the value, but I can't see how to do that, either.

Comment: Another way to ask is, why can't I "await document.readKey()"?

Comment: How was that rude. I said nothing about anyone but me. Perhaps you should keep your advice to yourself

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Let's break it down:

Is it possible to await a custom thing?

Yes — you can await any `Promise`. For example, to wait for a timeout:

```
const timerPromise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
await timerPromise;
```

Is it possible to have a promise for a key press?

Yes — resolve the promise when an event happens.

```
function readKey() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        window.addEventListener('keypress', resolve, {once:true});
    });
}
```

Comment: The whole application would need to be contained in an `async` IIFE would it not, if it has any chance of behaving like the OP described? `(async function() { ... }());` https://jsfiddle.net/9yn4nnr6/

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to @Kornel and @Xotic750, here's what I was looking for:

```
const readKey = () => new Promise(resolve => window.addEventListener('keypress', resolve, { once: true }));

(async function() {
  console.log('Press a key');
  const x = await readKey();
  console.log('Pressed', String.fromCharCode(x.which));

  console.log('Press a key');
  const y = await readKey();
  console.log('Pressed', String.fromCharCode(y.which));
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

This would wait until a keypress event on an element happens

```
await new Promise(r=>element.addEventListener('keypress', r));
```

---

Or a function to wait for any kind of events, can look like this

```
waitForEvent = (element, type) => new Promise(r=>element.addEventListener(type,r));
```

Then we can do things like

```
await waitForEvent(document, "load");
// or 
await waitForEvent(element, "keypress");
```